# Azure Devops extension (Build task) enable/disable or show/hide control based on user action

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-extensions

I am developing Azure Devops extension and I have requirement to enable/disable or show/hide control based on user action.

Please refer below image,

[image]

Requirement is once "Default Path" check box is ticked "Custom Path" input box should be disable or hide. And Once "Default Path" check box is tick is removed "Custom Path" input box should be enable or show.

Is this possible to achieve? Please be kind enough to share your thoughts on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, I am too interested in such a solution. Have you made any progress?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `visibleRule` property.

You could do it like so:

```
{
  "name": "defPath",
  "type": "boolean",
  "label": "Default path",
},
{
  "name": "customPathInput",
  "type": "string",
  "label": "Custom path",
  "visibleRule": "defPath = false"
},
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53240667/azure-devops-extension-custom-ui) for details.