# Azure DevOps extension custom UI

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I've been tasked to develop an extension for Azure DevOps to automate building process - a custom Build Task. The caveat is that in reality what I am developing is a series of build task, each containing regular inputs. But for historical reasons, all these build tasks should be grouped and the user would be able to choose the correct one from a drop-down list on the tasks' page in the pipeline settings.

The issue being is that the change in the drop down should hide SOME of the inputs and show some other inputs as well - i.e. I'd like to handle the CHANGE event of the drop-down and control the visibility of the UI elements.

Is this even possible?

Am I on the wrong track? How can I approach this?

Comment: Have you tried to maybe use a Task Group for creating bundled build task. You could also link selections into build variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simple, but it isn't obvious as of yet.

There is a property to each input, called `visibleRule` which does exactly whats needed: control the visibility of of the input it is attached to. So in the `task.json` file, in the `inputs` array, one could do this:

Define the drop-down:

```
{
  "name": "selectedOption",
  "type": "pickList",
  "label": "Options",
  "options": {
    "o1": "Option 1",
    "o2": "Option 2",
    "o3": "Option 3"
  }
},
```

Then define some fields like this:

```
{
  "name": "test1",
  "type": "string",
  "label": "Option 1 test",
  "visibleRule": "selectedOption = o1"
},
{
  "name": "test2",
  "type": "string",
  "label": "Option 2 test",
  "visibleRule": "selectedOption = o2"
},
```

Now the `test1` input is diplayed ONLY if `o1` (Option 1) is selected in the `selectedOption` drop-down. The same goes for `test2` and `o2`. Neither `test1` nor `test2` is displayed if the `selectedOption` is `o3`.

Comment: I find that I needed to "group" some controls together before it was visible with this snipped BEFORE the "inputs" section.

`"groups":[
      {
        "name": "SomeGroupName",
        "displayName" : "Group Title Goes Here",
        "isExpanded": true
      }`

Then in each control I added the property: `"groupName": "SomeGroupName"` . And it finally worked!