# Task.json azure devops extension hide input

Tags: azure-devops

```
"inputs":[     
{
             "name":"PathtoPublish",
             "type":"string",
             "label":"Path to publish",
             "defaultValue":"$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)",
             "required":true,
             "helpMarkDown":"The folder or file path to publish.",
             "visibleRule":"CommandType = Upload"
 },
```

[image]

in this custom task i created, *Path to publish* will always be $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory), so what I'm trying to do is to hide this so it doesn't show up in the task. I'm not sure if there is an attribute to HIDE IT, i tried adding HideInput: true

```
"inputs":[     
{
             "name":"PathtoPublish",
             "type":"string",
             "label":"Path to publish",
             "defaultValue":"$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)",
             "required":true,
             "helpMarkDown":"The folder or file path to publish.",
             "visibleRule":"CommandType = Upload",
             "HideInput": true
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [task.json schema](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/blob/master/tasks.schema.json), there isn't such an attribute to hide the input string `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`.
We can only use the `visibleRule` property to control the full visibility of the input label.

In your scenario, you have set `"visibleRule":"CommandType = Upload"`, that means the input `Path to publish` will be displayed only when the `Upload` command type is selected.

Another related thread for your reference : [Azure DevOps extension custom UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53240667/azure-devops-extension-custom-ui). Hope that helps.

Comment: @wonderfulworldwithcharity Is the reply helpful for you? Any update here?